# UISplitView equivalent on the iPhone.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an iPad app which I am attempting to make universal and port over to my iPhone following this tutorial. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/  (feel free to post a link if you believe it will help me).

So far, I have added a new storyboard file, named it Main_iPhone.storyboard and configured my target etc. However my iPad app is a UISplitView controller, with options on the side (in the master view) which control my detailview.

What I want to know is the iPhone equivalent of this object as i was made aware it cannot be used on the iPhone. Guidance needed on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: I think, thats you want..?
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: If you create a universal master/detail app from scratch, the iPhone version will use a navigation controller with a table view controller that pushes a detail view controller instead of the iPad's split view controller.

Comment: @aBilal17 I actually wanted to do it the "normal" way, not mimic the ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generalized answer since I have no idea what your app does.

The rootviewController of the app should be a navigation controller.  The the root controller of the navigation controller should be the view controller that is on the left side of the split view controller. I'm going to assume that is a tableviewController.

When the user selects a row in the tableview controller, push the view controller that was on the right side of the split controller.

Now you have a master-child relationship.

Comment: Yep, there is no direct equivalent for the split view on the iphone, which is logical as the screen is smaller. You can however create a similar user experience effect by letting the user browse through your content.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that with the upcoming iOS 8 release, you'll be able to easily implement iPad like master-detail views on iPhone. (the concept is size constraint classes). As a developer, you can download the new xcode beta (and osx yosemite beta) to test this out.

Comment: Shouldnt this be a comment rather than an answer?